# Stop playing video on modal video on close

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, bootstrap-4, bootstrap-modal

I tried couple of solutions from stack overflow but nothing seem to be working. If replace video tag with iframe, some solutions seems to work, but video autoplays again and spoils the solution.

```
    <div class="icon">
  <a>
  <button class="btn btn-link" data-target="#myModal" data-toggle="modal" type="button"><img src="https://sguru.org/wp-content/uploads/2018/02/YouTube.png" alt="" class="img-sm">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Click Here to Watch Training Video</button>
   </a>                                                                                                                                                                                  
</div>
<div aria-hidden="true" aria-labelledby="modal-sample-label" class="modal theme-alt modal-center-vertical" id="modal-sample" role="dialog" tabindex="-1">
    <div class="modal-dialog modal-lg">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <h4 class="modal-title" id="modal-sample-label">Video</h4>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
                <video controls="" id="video1" style="width: 100%; height: auto; margin:0 auto; frameborder:0;">
                    <source src="video.mp4" type="video/mp4">
                    Your browser doesn't support HTML5 video tag
                </video>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
                <button class="btn btn-info" data-dismiss="modal" type="button">Close</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `document.getElementById("video1").pause()` to pause the video when the modal is closed. Or, with jQuery, `$('#video1').pause()`.

Answer (score 0):

You cut put the video inside `ng-if`, the html gets removed, the video stops playing. If you have some animation like fade-out on the modal, set a timeout for the `ng-if variable` to remove it after the animation has finished.